# How to define an immutable object in a mutable Java class?

Tags: java, oop, object, immutability

In a class, I want to define an empty object and use it anywhere we need it. This object needs to be immutable to avoid accidentally modification. If this object is defined as a `public static final` member of the class, the object could be changed if the class itself is mutable.

What's the good way to create an immutable object in a mutable class?

Comment: If you want it to be immutable, then design the class to be immutable (or if you can't do that, then wrap it an a class that *is* immutable).

Comment: It's not possible. Either provide a method returning a new instance every time it's called, or define a read-only interface and make this the type  of the constant, or create a class that wraps the original class and prevents modification.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make a class immutable then you need to fulfill this requirements:

- all its fields final
- the class declared as final
- the this reference is not allowed to escape during construction
- Any fields which refer to mutable data objects are:

  - private
  - have no setter method
  - they are never directly returned of otherwise exposed to a caller
  - if they are changed internally in the class this change is not visible and has no effect outside of the class

Comment: That's correct but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the class to make it immutable (final class with final fields, etc.) than just write yourself an immutable wrapper (proxy from GOF?) and use it instead. Inside it can has a delegate to your original class instance.